# How to find the Standard error from a Variance-covariance matrix?

Tags: matrix, statistics, covariance, variance, standard-error

How can I find out the Standard error from a variance-covariance matrix?

Is it just the Squared root of diagonal values? or else the Squared root of the ratio between diagonal values and the no of observations?

Comment: In many statistics software products, the standard error is shortened with `S(E)`. However, a sample output would be helpful here.

Comment: The standard error of the parameter estimates from the variance-covariance matrix is the square root of the diagonal values.